# Enabling HTML5 mode to true in an angular frontend and laravel backend is not working properly

Tags: php, angularjs, html, laravel, .htaccess

I wanted to remove **"#!"** from my website URL. And I was able to set it up perfectly and it's working.

The problem is when I go to any sub URL apart from home and reload the page, then it says page not found. But I am able to open the same sub URL when I click on a link in the home page.

for example,

Home page URL: http://abcxyz.com

Sub URL:: http://abcxyz.com/qaz

I have set up the HTML 5 mode in my angular application in the following way:

1) Enabling HTML 5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

2) Setting base tag

In index.blade.php file and in the head tag, I am setting:

```
<base href="/" />
```

3) Setting htaccess

Again, I tried setting my .htaccess file in this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Also I am using Laravel Back-end. So please help me set up my .htaccess file properly as I am definitely missing something here. Or if this issue is because of something else, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the virtual host, then use following in /etc/apache/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/docroot/dist/
     <Directory /var/www/html/docroot/dist/>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise, use these redirects in your .htaccess file.
This should solve your **suburl page not found** problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Omkar, but these redirects didn't work for me. I have an angular front end with laravel backend. The angular routes kicks in only when every URL is redirected to the home page

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding one more route in my web.php file in laravel:

```
Route::any('{any}',function(){
    return view('index');
})->where('any','.*');
```

I know we can achieve this through htaccess. Any help will be appreciated.
However, this solution is working for me for now.